# hypanis.ru wordpress vulnerabilty

Tags: errors, fatal-error

Does anyone know anything about the "**hypanis.ru**" wordpress vulnerability?

A client has recently got a WP virus which has caused his website to output "hypanis.ru" before the headers on ever page. This results in the following error:

hypanis.ru

*Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/html/wp-includes/load.php(1) : runtime-created function:10) in /home/content/html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1219*

A search for this in Google shows absolutely no posts/information, but over 29,000 sites that are affected with the same virus: [https://www.google.com/search?q="hypanis.ru"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22hypanis.ru%22)

This seems like a lot of sites affected, for a virus that doesn't show up on any wordpress vulnerability list or database? Does anyone have any information on this please?

Comment: Not sure why this is "too localized" when there are over 29,000 sites affected by this vulnerability and no solution proposed.

Answer (score 2):

I would more suspect a code injection via a plugin's vulnerability; there have been a few of those lately. I don't think it is a virus; just someone that exploited an unpatched vulnerability.

You don't specify whether the site has been updated (WP, plugins, themes) or the PHP version; this would be useful information.

To clean, I would upload fresh/clean versions of all theme and plugin code (deleting those plugin/theme folder's contents first), then upload a fresh WP (everything except your wp-config.php).

I'd also look at your htaccess files, and any custom Child Themes, for any inserted/invalid code. A good database backup is a good idea; and an inspection of the wp-contents table for inserted or modified post records.

And, of course, strong passwords everywhere (WP, database, hosting, FTP); an admin user that is not called 'admin' (and not user #1), and strong passwords on all admin-level accounts.

Comment: Thank you, all good suggestions I will try, although I am more interested in finding some information out about this vulnerability that has been exploited on over 29,000 wordpress sites, and no one seems to know anything about! Unfortunately this topic was deemed "too localized", so I guess me and 29,000 other webmasters will continue to know nothing about this massive exploit!

Comment: The point is not the 'result' of the attack, but how the attacker got into your system. The result could have been anything. It's possible that the attacker got into all of those systems via a vuln in a plugin that all sites used. The 'result' is not the issue, but how they got in, and how to fix it. My suggestions are how to fix (and how to prevent future successful attacks). Hacked sites, unfortunately, are not within the scope of the questions here, so your question was closed. I try to answer them before closure, because I think that many will search here for that issue.